# Set all months in a list or map along with years

Tags: java, list, monthcalendar

I want to set a list or map which ever is preferable,
I'll get a month and a year as input,for example
consider input is 

`Feb-2015`

then a list or map must contain months and year for next 12 months.
Like

`feb-2015
march-2015
apr-2015
may-215....`
till

`feb-2016`

How to set a map or list in the above mentioned manner?

Comment: Nothing actually!!

Comment: You said "12 months" but in your example your fill 13 months.

Comment: @FrancisRaj Well, this is your issue.

Comment: "I want to set a list or map which ever is preferable" - how could we know? What are you trying to do with that list or map or whatever? Have a look at  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html and the whole new Java Time API ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Demo{
    public static void main(String[]args)throws ParseException{
        final String input="Mar-2016";
        final SimpleDateFormat fmt=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");//same as above format
        Date date=fmt.parse(input);
        final Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();//as of now
        cal.setTime(date);//set to input
        final int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);//gives index 0 - 11, Jan - Dec
        List<String> dates=new ArrayList<>();
        do{
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);//adds month one-by-one
            date=cal.getTime();//give date 
            dates.add(fmt.format(date));//date to string as per above format
        }while(month!=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));//unitl next year of given input month
        System.out.println(dates);
    }
}
```

[Code on My YouTube Channel](https://youtu.be/sHzzQ5m5CuA)